# Swift C void* and void** pointers in latest betas (4)

Tags: c, swift

In previous betas, I was able to pass a pointer to anything to C doing something like this

```
var aString : NSString = "This is a string" // create an NSString
var anUnmanaged = Unmanaged.passUnretained(aString) // take an unmanaged pointer
var opaque : COpaquePointer = anUnmanaged.toOpaque() // convert it to a COpaquePointer
var mut : CMutablePointer = &opaque // this is a CMutablePointer
doSomething(mut) // pass the pointer to an helper function written in C
```

With the C function like this:

```
void doSomething(void ** ptr)
{
   // do something with the pointer, change it and make it point to another nsstring for example
}
```

Now, (for sure in Beta4, maybe even in Beta3) the syntax translated from C to Swift has changed

Before, the doSomething function was expecting a CMutablePointer (that now has been removed from Swift)
Now, it expects a:

```
UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<()>>
```

() is a typealias to Void

So, syntactically talking is more clear.
However, Now I can't understand how to take the void** pointer of any object like I was doing in previous betas.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var p: UnsafePointer<Void> = unsafeAddressOf(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
let strPtr = unsafeBitCast(aString, UnsafePointer<Void>.self)
let strPtrPtr = unsafeBitCast(strPtr, UnsafePointer<Void>.self)
```

And then:

```
doSomething(strPtrPtr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct answer, I hope that someone has a better method to do this.
The main problem was that there is no direct conversion between a Swift Object and a Void UnsafePointer ( `UnsafePointer<()>` )
However I managed how to do it passing through a COpaquePointer

```
    // since I can't go directly from NSMutableString to UnsafePointer<()> (which is UnsafePointer<Void>) i pass through a COpaquePointer
    var aString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: "test") // create an NSString
    var anUnmanaged = Unmanaged.passUnretained(aString) // take an unmanaged pointer
    var opaque : COpaquePointer = anUnmanaged.toOpaque() // convert it to a COpaquePointer
    var anUnsafe : UnsafePointer<()> = UnsafePointer(opaque) // convert it to an UnsafePointer to Void ( () is a Typealias to Void) using the init(_ other: COpaquePointer) initializer

    doSomething(&anotherUnsafe)
```